# How to set new properties, or push to array with async and await, within callback function?

Tags: javascript, meteor, vue.js

When I use async/await with rawCollection and get data inside a loop, and then set new properties (poTmp), it works as expected. But after I set new properties and console.log outside it doesn't set new props. Why?

```
let items = await Items.rawCollection()
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: match,
      },
    ])
    .toArray()

  let data = items
  data.forEach(async item => {
    let po = await PurchaseOrderDetails.rawCollection()
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            itemId: item._id,
            tranDate: { $lte: tDate },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$itemId',
            itemDoc: { $last: item },
            onHandPO: { $sum: '$qtyBase' },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$itemId',
            itemDoc: { $last: '$itemDoc' },
            lastOnHandPO: { $last: '$onHandPO' },
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray()
    //==================
    //set new properties
    //==================
    item.poTmp = po[0]

  })
  console.log(data)
  return data
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
data.forEach(async item => {
```

async functions return promises immediately when invoked, so the forEach completes and moves on to the `console.log` line.

The async work delegated to the async functions has not yet completed at this point and so the data is not yet modified.

Since it seems you are already in an async function (since you've used await higher in the code), you can wait for all the promises to resolve with `await` and `Promise.all`

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises, so instead of `forEach` we can use `map` to create an array of promises

```
await Promise.all( data.map(async item => { ...
```

Like `forEach`, `map` will iterate over all of the items and run the given function. Unlike `forEach`, `map` will return an array with the results of these functions, and given they are async functions, each one will return a promise.

Now we use `Promise.all` to create a single promise that will resolve when every one of the async functions have finished. And we use `await` to tell the function to pause until that new promise resolves.

Pausing the function with `await` means the console.log won't run until every one of those async functions have finished, meaning it will have the correct data when it does run.

Comment: Hey Fred could you right out "await Promise.all( data.map(aysnc item => { ..." more fully? I'm having trouble following your code without the rest. I'm also not just asking because I want free code, I'm also trying to understand how to solve this problem . I saw Promise.all on another website and I think that might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example anyone who needs it:

```
  public async updateBatch(req:any,res:any){

        body = [1,3,4,5,6]

        var rfinal:number[] = [];

        await Promise.all(body.map(async items=>{

            let newStatus = 'MJ';

                inputParameters = [
                { name: 'PID', dataType: sql.Int, value: items },
                { name: 'Status', dataType: sql.VarChar, value: newStatus }
            ];

            let CustomQuery = `UPDATE MYTable 
                SET Status= @Status
                WHERE PID= @PID`;

            const result = await provider.executeQuery(CustomQuery, inputParameters).catch(err => {
                    LogErrors.logErrors(err);
            });
            if(result.rowsAffected[0]>0){
                    rfinal.push(result.rowsAffected[0]);
            }else{
                throw new console.error('Un expected error, updating newsfeed');
            }

        })
        );

  }
```